# Excel - sum base on row and multiple columns

Tags: excel-2010, sumifs

How to get sum of column labels 15 and 8 of a particular date

Input:

[image]

Output: need for all rows

[image]

One way is do sum along horizontal yet not sure to  match the dates... I have >50K columns in real dataset.  sumif along rows link https://exceljet.net/formula/sumifs-with-horizontal-range

Comment: I didn't understand, what do you have to do? I don't see any 18 or 5 labels

Comment: Thanks, edited in my post. 15 and 8 are columns names

Comment: You have to sum all the columns 15 and 8?

Comment: for full expression, I have added full expected output.  eg. the entry 351.41 for 1/1/2014 corresponds to sum of all values (58.92,40.58,61.94,34.43,8.27,230.55) in Input table with column name '15'

Comment: I don't know if it youll work for you, but have you tried DSUM ?

Answer (score 1):

you can write this in the cell where you want the result of first row:

```
=FIRSTCELL + SECONDCELL + THIRDCELL ecc...
```

where firstcell is like "A3"..

after simply select the cell where you got the result, a dot appears in the lower right of the cell, drag it down, and in the cells below you will get the result of the other rows

Comment: Not sure I can do that, I have more than 5K columns in my real dataset

Comment: One thing I can use sumifs along rows , yet not sure to match the dates     https://exceljet.net/formula/sumifs-with-horizontal-range

Comment: Maybe use that formula and set your range by using the OFFSET function (use MATCH for column)